# Help debugging my session? Rails 3 ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception

Even though I'm pretty sure I know why this error gets raised, I don't seem to know why or how my session is exceeding the 4KB limit...

My app was working fine, but once I deliberately started adding bugs to see if my transactions were rolling back I started getting this error.

To give some background, I'm busy coding a tournament application that (in this section) will create the tournament and then add some tournament legs based on the number of teams as well as populate the the tournament with some 'ghost fixtures' once the legs have been created.

The flash[:tournament] was working correctly before; using a tournament object, I have access to any AR validation errors as well as data that has been entered on the previous page to create the tournament.

*TournamentController.rb*

```
begin
  <other code>
  Tournament.transaction do
    tournament.save!
    Tournament.generate_legs tournament
    Tournament.generate_ghost_fixtures tournament
  end

  flash[:notice] = "Tournament created!"
  redirect_to :action => :index
rescue Exception => e
  flash[:tournament] = tournament
  redirect_to :action => :new, :notice => "There was an error!"
end
```

*Tournament.rb*

```
self.generate_ghost_fixtures(tournament)
  <other code>
  #Generate the ghost fixtures
  #tournament_legs is a has_many association
  tournament_legs_array = tournament.tournament_legs

  tournament_legs_array.each do |leg|
    number_of_fixtures = matches[leg.leg_code]

    #For the first round of a 32 team tournament, this block will run 16 times to create the matches
    number_of_fixtures.times do |n|
      Fixture.creatse!(:tournament_leg_id => leg.id, :match_code => "#{leg.leg_code}-#{n+1}")
    end
  end
end
```

I can do nothing but speculate as to why my session variable is exceeding 4KB??
Is it possible that the tournament object I pass through the flash variable contains all the associations as well?

Here is the dump of my session once I get the error.

Hope this is enough info to help me out :)

Thanks

*Session Dump*

```
_csrf_token: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
flash: {:tournament=>#<Tournament id: nil, tournament_name: "asd", tournament_description: "asdasd", game_id: 1, number_of_teams: 16, start_date: "2011-04-30 00:00:00", tournament_style: "single elimination", tournament_status: "Drafting", active: true, created_at: "2011-04-30 10:07:28", updated_at: "2011-04-30 10:07:28">}
player_id: 1
session_id: "4e5119cbaee3d5d09111f49cf47aa8fa"
```

Comment: It seems that the flash[:tournament] = tournament in the rescue clause is the culprit.

Comment: Yep, it is the culprit, what I want to know is how the hell does the cookie exceed 4Kb ... :D Associations? I dunno.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

About dependencies, it is possible. Also save an ActiveRecord instance in the session is not a recommended aproach. You should save only the id. If you need it in all your requests use a before filter to retrieve it.

You can read more why is a bad idea at: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/13-dangers-of-model-in-session

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not wise to save big objects as a session variable, was kinda wondering more about the unique situation I found myself in...

Answer (score 3):

The generally accepted and recommended approach is to *not* use a redirect on error, but a direct render instead. The standard "controller formula" is this:

```
def create
  @tournament = Tournament.new(params[:tournament])
  if @tournament.save
    redirect ...
  else
    render 'new'  # which will have access to the errors on the @tournament object and any other instance variable you may define
  end
end

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_up_legs
end
```

On successful saving, you can drop all instance variables (thereby wiping the in-memory state) and redirect to another page. On failure (or exception) you keep the object in memory and render a view template instead (typically the 'new' or 'edit' form page). If you're using standard Rails validation and error handling, then the object will have an errors array that you can just display.

I'd also recommend you use ActiveRecord associations which automatically give you transactions. If you push all this into the model, e.g. a "set_up_legs" method or something, then you can use ActiveRecord error handling. This is part of the ["skinny controller, fat model"](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) paradigm.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply to your response, I agree with everything  you say regarding the better pratices. I also understand why using these better practises would completely avoid this error from happening. I am, however, still scratching my head as to why the cookie can be more than 4kB... I want to understand why this happens. Thanks again. p.s. Really enjoyed your screencasts on RSpec. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

in session_store.rb, uncomment the last line with :active_record_store
Now restart the server

Comment: doesn't really answer the question... but still helpful in some situations when you want to use the database to store.

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the exception to string before assigning it to flash[:tournament] with 'to_s'.
I had the same error and it seems assigning an exception object to a session variabla like flash means it takes the whole stack trace with it into the session. Try it, worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the response Peter, I will have a bash at it!